# Order string alpha numerically A1-1-1, A1-2-1, A1-10-1, A1-2-2, A1-2-3 etc

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sorting

I have a column with different length strings which has dashes (-) that separates alphanumeric strings.
The string could look like "A1-2-3".
I need to order by first "A1" then "2" then "3"

I want to achieve the following order for the column:

```
A1
A1-1-1
A1-1-2
A1-1-3
A1-2-1
A1-2-2
A1-2-3
A1-7
A2-1-1
A2-1-2
A2-1-3
A2-2-1
A2-2-2
A2-2-3
A2-10-1
A2-10-2
A2-10-3
A10-1-1
A10-1-2
A10-1-3
A10-2-1
A10-2-2
A10-2-3
```

I can separate the string with the following code:

```
declare @string varchar(max) = 'A1-2-3'
declare @first varchar(max) = SUBSTRING(@string,1,charindex('-',@string)-1)
declare @second varchar(max) = substring(@string, charindex('-',@string) + 1, charindex('-',reverse(@string))-1)
declare @third varchar(max) = right(@string,charindex('-',reverse(@string))-1)

select @first, @second, @third
```

With the above logic I thought that I could use the following:
Note this only regards strings with 2 dashes

```
select barcode from tabelWithBarcodes
order by
case when len(barcode) - len(replace(barcode,'-','')) = 2 then
        len(SUBSTRING(barcode,1,charindex('-',barcode)-1))
    end
 , case when len(barcode) - len(replace(barcode,'-','')) = 2 then
     SUBSTRING(barcode,1,(charindex('-',barcode)-1))
 end


,  case when len(barcode) - len(replace(barcode,'-','')) = 2 then
        len(substring(barcode, charindex('-',barcode) + 1, charindex('-',reverse(barcode))-1))
    end
, case when len(barcode) - len(replace(barcode,'-','')) = 2 then
        substring(barcode, charindex('-',barcode) + 1, charindex('-',reverse(barcode))-1)
    end


, case when len(barcode) - len(replace(barcode,'-','')) = 2 then
    len(right(barcode,charindex('-',reverse(barcode))-1))
end
, case when len(barcode) - len(replace(barcode,'-','')) = 2 then
    right(barcode,charindex('-',reverse(barcode))-1)
end
```

But the sorting is not working for the second and third section of the string.
(I haven't added the code for checking if the string has only 1 or no dash in it for simplicity)

Not sure if I'm on the right path here.
Is anybody able to solve this?

Comment: Will parts 2 and 3 always be a numerical value? Will the left most character always be an alpha, and any remaining numerical? I.e. could you have values such as `'AB1-1-2' or `A17-A4-9'`?

Comment: I suggest doing the split on a CTE or subquery then finding out the proper order expression outside. This way you don't have to repeat all the parsing code each time.

Comment: To answer, however, why your ordering isn't as you expect, numbers and strings are ordered differently. With numbers `10 > 2`, however, with strings `'2' > '10'`. Strings are ordered in order by their characters left to right. `'2' > '1'` and thus `'2'` has  a "greater" value than `'10'`.

Comment: Your data is not normalized, at least in the sense that each data point may convey several pieces of sorting information.  If you really have a long term need to sort this way, then I recommend storing each digit in a separate column.

Comment: @Larnu. Yes and I could get 'AB1-2-E1' too.

Comment: @EzLo. Do you have a suggestion how that code would look like?

Comment: What's your SQL Server release?

Comment: @dnoeth. Sql Server 2016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up to 3 dashes can be covered by fiddling with `replace` & `parsename` & `patindex`:

```
declare @TabelWithBarcodes table (id int primary key identity(1,1), barcode varchar(20) not null, unique (barcode));

insert into @TabelWithBarcodes (barcode) values
('2-2-3'),('A2-2-2'),('A2-2-1'),('A2-10-3'),('A2-10-2'),('A2-10-1'),('A2-1-3'),('A2-1-2'),('A2-1-1'),
('A10-2-3'),('A10-2-2'),('A10-2-10'),('A10-1-3'),('AA10-A111-2'),('A10-1-1'),
('A1-7'),('A1-2-3'),('A1-2-12'),('A1-2-1'),('A1-1-3'),('B1-1-2'),('A1-1-1'),('A1'),('A10-10-1'),('A12-10-1'), ('AB1-2-E1') ;

with cte as 
 (
   select barcode,
      replace(BarCode, '-', '.')
      + replicate('.0', 3 - (len(BarCode)-len(replace(BarCode, '-', '')))) as x
from @TabelWithBarcodes
 )
select * 
,  substring(parsename(x,4), 1, patindex('%[0-9]%',parsename(x,4))-1)
  ,cast(substring(parsename(x,4), patindex('%[0-9]%',parsename(x,4)), 10) as int)
  ,substring(parsename(x,3), 1, patindex('%[0-9]%',parsename(x,3))-1)
  ,cast(substring(parsename(x,3), patindex('%[0-9]%',parsename(x,3)), 10) as int)
  ,substring(parsename(x,2), 1, patindex('%[0-9]%',parsename(x,2))-1)
  ,cast(substring(parsename(x,2), patindex('%[0-9]%',parsename(x,2)), 10) as int)
  ,substring(parsename(x,1), 1, patindex('%[0-9]%',parsename(x,1))-1)
  ,cast(substring(parsename(x,1), patindex('%[0-9]%',parsename(x,1)), 10) as int)
from cte
order by
  substring(parsename(x,4), 1, patindex('%[0-9]%',parsename(x,4))-1)
  ,cast(substring(parsename(x,4), patindex('%[0-9]%',parsename(x,4)), 10) as int)
  ,substring(parsename(x,3), 1, patindex('%[0-9]%',parsename(x,3))-1)
  ,cast(substring(parsename(x,3), patindex('%[0-9]%',parsename(x,3)), 10) as int)
  ,substring(parsename(x,2), 1, patindex('%[0-9]%',parsename(x,2))-1)
  ,cast(substring(parsename(x,2), patindex('%[0-9]%',parsename(x,2)), 10) as int)
  ,substring(parsename(x,1), 1, patindex('%[0-9]%',parsename(x,1))-1)
  ,cast(substring(parsename(x,1), patindex('%[0-9]%',parsename(x,1)), 10) as int)
```

1. extend each barcode to 4 groups by adding trailing `.0` if missing
2. split each barcode in 4 groups
3. split each group in leading characters and trailing digits
4. sort by the leading character first
5. then by casting the digits as numeric

See [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=64c1e6eef62bab7f0368246f9052eacb)

Comment: Should `'B2'` be sorted before `'A10'` (this solution will)?

Comment: @Larnu: A10 must come before B2. But the above code is pretty close

Comment: @Larnu: fixed :-)

Comment: Looks good. :) I;d be interested in testing this against my own for speed, but that means make a large dataset. I'll have a good. +1 though.

Answer (score 2):

This is not pretty, however...

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

WITH VTE AS(
    SELECT V.SomeString
          --Randomised order
    FROM (VALUES ('A1-1-1'),
                 ('A10-1-3'),
                 ('A10-2-2'),
                 ('A1-1-3'),
                 ('A10-2-1'),
                 ('A2-2-2'),
                 ('A1-2-1'),
                 ('A1-2-2'),
                 ('A2-1-1'),
                 ('A10-1-2'),
                 ('B2-1-2'),
                 ('A1'),
                 ('A2-2-1'),
                 ('A2-10-3'),
                 ('A10-2-3'),
                 ('A2-1-2'),
                 ('B1-4'),
                 ('A2-10-2'),
                 ('A2-2-3'),
                 ('A10-1-1'),
                 ('A1-A1-3'),
                 ('A1-7'),
                 ('A2-10-1'),
                 ('A2-1-3'),
                 ('A1-1-2'),
                 ('A1-2-3')) V(SomeString)),
Splits AS(
    SELECT V.SomeString,
           DS.Item,
           DS.ItemNumber,
           CONVERT(int,STUFF((SELECT '' + NG.token
                              FROM dbo.NGrams8k(DS.item,1) NG
                              WHERE TRY_CONVERT(int, NG.Token) IS NOT NULL
                              ORDER BY NG.position
                              FOR XML PATH('')),1,0,'')) AS NumericPortion
    FROM VTE V
         CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(V.SomeString,'-') DS),
Pivoted AS(
    SELECT S.SomeString,
           MIN(CASE V.P1 WHEN S.Itemnumber THEN REPLACE(S.Item, S.NumericPortion,'') END) AS P1Alpha,
           MIN(CASE V.P1 WHEN S.Itemnumber THEN S.NumericPortion END) AS P1Numeric,
           MIN(CASE V.P2 WHEN S.Itemnumber THEN REPLACE(S.Item, S.NumericPortion,'') END) AS P2Alpha,
           MIN(CASE V.P2 WHEN S.Itemnumber THEN S.NumericPortion END) AS P2Numeric,
           MIN(CASE V.P3 WHEN S.Itemnumber THEN REPLACE(S.Item, S.NumericPortion,'') END) AS P3Alpha,
           MIN(CASE V.P3 WHEN S.Itemnumber THEN S.NumericPortion END) AS P3Numeric
    FROM Splits S
         CROSS APPLY (VALUES(1,2,3)) AS V(P1,P2,P3)
    GROUP BY S.SomeString)
SELECT P.SomeString
FROM Pivoted P
ORDER BY P.P1Alpha,
         P.P1Numeric,
         P.P2Alpha,
         P.P2Numeric,
         P.P3Alpha,
         P.P3Numeric;
```

This outputs:

```
A1
A1-1-1
A1-1-2
A1-1-3
A1-2-1
A1-2-2
A1-2-3
A1-7
A1-A1-3
A2-1-1
A2-1-2
A2-1-3
A2-2-1
A2-2-2
A2-2-3
A2-10-1
A2-10-2
A2-10-3
A10-1-1
A10-1-2
A10-1-3
A10-2-1
A10-2-2
A10-2-3
B1-4
B2-1-2
```

This makes use of 2 user defined functions. Firstly or [DelimitedSplit8k_Lead](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SQL+Server+2012/106903/) (I used [DelimitedSplit8k](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) as I don't have the other on my sandbox at the moment). Then you also have [NGrams8k](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/142316/).

I really should explain how this works, but yuck... (edit coming).

OK... (/sigh) What it does. Firstly, we split the data into its relevant parts using `delimitedsplit8k(_lead)`. Then, within the `SELECT` we use `FOR XML PATH` to get (**only**) the nuemrical part of that string (For example, for `'A10'` we get `'10'`) and we convert it to a numerical value (an `int`).

Then we pivot that data out into respective parts. The alphanumerical part, and the numerical part. So, for the value `'A10-A1-12'` we end up with the row:

```
'A', 10, 'A', 1, 12
```

Then, now that we've pivoted the data, we sort it by each column individually. And voila.

This ***will*** fall over if you have a value like `'A1A'` or `'1B1'`, and honestly, I'm not changing it to catter for that. This was messy, and really isn't what the RDBMS should be doing.

Comment: Very Cool! Thank you

Comment: You're welcome @SCDK but i suggest you take Tim's comment on board. Normalise your data is such a sort order is important.

Answer (score 0):

An alterative approach would be to use your technique to split the string into its 3 component parts, then left pad those strings with leading zeros (or characters of your choice).  That avoids any issues where the string may contain alphanumerics rather than just numerics.  However, it does mean that strings containing different length alphabetic characters may not be sorted as you may expect... Here's the code to play with (using the definitions from [@dnoeth's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54128570/361842)):

```
;with cte as 
(
   select barcode
   , case 
       when barcode like '%-%' then 
           substring(barcode,1,charindex('-',barcode)-1) 
       else 
           barcode 
       end part1
   , case 
       when barcode like '%-%' then 
           substring(barcode, charindex('-',barcode) + 1, case 
               when barcode like '%-%-%' then 
                   (charindex('-',barcode,charindex('-',barcode) + 1)) - 1 
               else 
                   len(barcode) 
               end 
           - charindex('-',barcode))
       else 
           '' 
       end part2
   , case 
       when barcode like '%-%-%' then 
           right(barcode,charindex('-',reverse(barcode))-1) --note: assumes you don't have %-%-%-%
       else 
           '' 
       end part3 
   from @TabelWithBarcodes
)
select barcode
, part1, part2, part3
, right('0000000000' + coalesce(part1,''), 10) lpad1
, right('0000000000' + coalesce(part2,''), 10) lpad2
, right('0000000000' + coalesce(part3,''), 10) lpad3
from cte
order by lpad1, lpad2, lpad3
```

[DBFiddle Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8d669cd0e63c7192fa3c05269677fe18)

Comment: This suffers the same problem as dnoeth's though. `'B2'` < `'A10'`. It should be the other way round. [DB<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e85fb5fa8dfc682e0e9d25c9651f0d25).

Comment: Ah good point @Larnu, thanks... It's at times like these I wish there was proper regex support in SQL (without having to delve into bespoke CLR functions).